# iPhone Global class with categories, is this correct?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My singleton global class has **all these categeories in same class**, in header file their interfaces and in implemantation file their implementations as below,

This works, but I am not quite sure what I am doing is good practise here because it is a singleton class already and I am calling these methods as categories and doing some allocates, releases..and stuff. or they are alreday outside of the global class cause they are different implemantations?

Can you tell me if everything is correct here?

```
#import "GlobalConfig.h"
#import "SynthesizeSingleton.h"
@implementation GlobalConfig
SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(GlobalConfig);
@end

@implementation UIColor (APP)
+(UIColor *) APP_NAV_COLOR { return [UIColor colorWithRed:00/256.0 green:111/256.0    
                                                 blue:59/256.0 alpha:1.0]; }
+(UIColor *) APP_BUTTON_COLOR { return [UIColor colorWithRed:00/256.0 green:00/256.0    
@end

@implementation UIImage(APP)
+(UIImage *) APP_IMAGE_BCKGROUND {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bckPhone" ofType:@"png"];
return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfResolutionIndependentFile:path]; 
}
@end

@implementation CALayer(APP)
+(CALayer *) APP_SELECTION_VIEW:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = cellView.bounds;   
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor APP_WHITE_COLOR] CGColor],    (id)[[UIColor APP_BLACK_COLOR] CGColor], nil];  
[cellView release];
return gradient;
}
@end

@implementation UIView(APP)
+(UIView *) APP_BACKGROUND_VIEW:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
UIView *cellView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
CAGradientLayer *gradient2 = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient2.frame = cellView2.bounds;
gradient2.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
gradient2.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5);
gradient2.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor APP_WHITE_COLOR] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor APP_COLOR] CGColor], nil];
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient2 atIndex:0];
[cellView2 release];
UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
 myBackView.backgroundColor=[[UIColor APP_COLOR] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];
[myBackView autorelease];
return myBackView;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend existing classes (i.e., `CALayer`, `UIImage`, and `UIColor`) through categories, you don't need a singleton.

A singleton is a class that you use to instantiate a single object (and have a guarantee at that is unique). A  category is a way to extend an existing interface, *without adding* any ivars (only methods) and due to this you don't need to instantiate a category before using it. So categories and singletons responds to different requirements and there is no need to mix them.

You can simply define your categories like you do, and then use them with your UIView, UIColor and CALAyer objects.

Comment: tnx I should create another non-singleton utiliy class and put all my categories in it?

Comment: If you want, you can create a utility file and put all the categories (each category counts as a class/interface syntactically) there. Then you will import all of them at once when you use it. Or you could have separate files, so you can import them one by one.

Comment: I just removed them to another class, and I got warnings from other classes which were using them as they may not respond to that method? do I have to import that class manually to every class I use? and no need to instantiate I guess?

Comment: exactly, you need to import the headers where you use it (to remove the warnings), and no need for instantiation.

Comment: tnx worked, if you see any other bad usage above pls let me know

Answer (score 1):

Well a singleton class is intended or creating a single instance for the class and use the same throughout  the life cycle.

This is not safe in any of 2 conditions
1. as long as you have the interface declarations of subclasses in GlobalConfig.h file.
2. if you have used shared singleton object of GlobalConfig in any of the subclasses/extensions

so i think its always better to create seperate files like UIView+AppExtensions ,  UIImage+AppExtensions

Comment: tnx I should create another non-singleton utiliy class and put all my categories in it? and when should i call that class?